# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: DatagramSocketDataEvent

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to use `DatagramSocket` in a ActionScript3 project in Flash CS6 but after compiling, I get this error:

> DatagramSocketClass.as, Line 24   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: `DatagramSocketDataEvent`.

and this is my `DatagramSocketClass.as` code:

```
package com.example.udp
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class DatagramSocketClass extends Sprite
    {
        private var datagramSocket:DatagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        public function World()
        {

            datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            datagramSocket.bind("1111","127.0.0.1");
            datagramSocket.addEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, dataReceived );
            datagramSocket.receive();
        }


        private function dataReceived( event:DatagramSocketDataEvent ):void
        {
            //Read the data from the datagram
            log("Received");
        }
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagram sockets are only available on AIR2 (and even then only on desktop - not mobile). Are you sure you want to use datagram sockets to begin with? "Regular" TCP sockets are usually sufficient (and safer and easier to use).

Comment: Really thanks for your response, @Jonatan. Actually I want to connect to an UDP connection via Flash Player (I mention flash player because I want to run the application on web browsers), is it possible to connect to an UDP with Regular TCP socket?

Comment: UDP doesn't have connections, strictly speaking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP). What are you trying to achieve? There might be better ways to do it. It's not possible to use UDP through TCP (not directly anyway, it's probably possible to build a proxy server that translates, but then everything would have to go through that).

Comment: Let me say what I want to do. I have a SIP proxy (VoIP) written with c++ that open a UDP and send sound packets over this, and then, I want to connect to this port with Flash (and ActionScript) to play the sound in browser. Exactly this is a media streaming. So, what's the best solution for receiving sound packets from another application and play them?

Comment: It might be possible through some other technology, such as java applets. Or if you set up a proxy that takes in the UDP packets and makes a TCP stream from it, which is then sent to the flash clients. This will probably have a lot of latency and increase the required bandwidth greatly however.

Comment: What about using some other methods on ActionScript like NetStream or RTMP?

Comment: That should certainly be possible if the server can serve data in that format :)